# FirstIn and LastOut is not working

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I want to calculate total working hours of an employee for specific day. With my current query it is giving me records for all days but what I want is to get for each day.
Like I have 2 days records so it should show 2 rows but instead it is only returning one.

```
DECLARE @T TABLE 
    ([EmpID] int, [TimeIn] datetime, [TimeOut] datetime);

INSERT INTO @T
    ([EmpID], [TimeIn], [TimeOut]) VALUES
    (1, '2018-01-10 9:00:00', NULL),
    (1, NULL, '2018-01-10 11:00'),
    (1, '2018-01-10 11:30:00', NULL),
    (1, NULL, '2018-01-10 13:00'),
    (1, '2018-01-10 13:30:00', NULL),
    (1, NULL, '2018-01-10 18:00'),
    (1, '2018-01-11 9:00:00', NULL),
    (1, NULL, '2018-01-11 11:00'),
    (1, '2018-01-11 11:30:00', NULL),
    (1, NULL, '2018-01-11 13:00'),
    (1, '2018-01-11 13:30:00', NULL),
    (1, NULL, '2018-01-11 18:00')
;
;WITH TM
AS
(
SELECT
    EmpID, 
    MIN([TimeIn]) as StartTime,
    MAX([TimeOut]) as EndTime
    FROM @T
    GROUP BY EmpId
)
SELECT
    *,
    HoursSpent = DATEDIFF(HOUR, StartTime, EndTime)
    FROM TM
```

What I really want is that by default it should give me yesterday's report or otherwise I could pass value at run time too like I want report of 10th Jan 2018 and something like that but I guess that part is far away as I'm stuck here.

Comment: What version of sql? Do you have LEAD? Assuming the rows always come in pair, first row is time in, following is time out.

Comment: I'm using sql server 2012. Yes but the structure I'm suppose to follow doesn't put the time in pair.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
;WITH cte AS
(
SELECT empid
    , MIN(timein) timein
    , MAX(timeout) timeout
    , cast(coalesce(timein, timeout) AS DATE) d
    FROM @T
    GROUP BY empid, cast(coalesce(timein, timeout) AS DATE)
)
SELECT empid
, d AS Day
, DateDiff(HOUR, TimeIn, TimeOut) [Hours Worked]
FROM cte
ORDER BY d ASC
```

Answer (score 1):

```
;WITH 
TM1 as
(
    SELECT  EmpID, 
        convert(date, COALESCE(TimeIn, [TimeOut])) as [Date], 
        TimeIn, 
        [TimeOut], 
        grp = (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY EmpID ORDER BY COALESCE(TimeIn, [TimeOut])) - 1) / 2 + 1
    from    @T
),
TM2
AS
(
    SELECT  EmpID, 
        [Date],
        DATEDIFF(HOUR, MIN([TimeIn]), MAX([TimeOut])) as HoursSpent
    FROM    TM1
    GROUP BY EmpID, [Date], grp
)
SELECT  EmpID, [Date], SUM(HoursSpent) as HoursSpent
FROM    TM2
GROUP BY EmpID, [Date]

/*
RESULT : 
EmpID  Date         HoursSpent
  1    2018-01-10   9
  1    2018-01-11   9
*/
```

if you want higher precision, use DATEDIFF(minute) and divide by 60.0

Comment: `1 NULL 2018-01-11 18:00:00.000 NULL
1 2018-01-10 09:00:00.000 NULL NULL
1 2018-01-11 09:00:00.000 NULL NULL`

This is what I got

Comment: I can't put TimeIn and TiemOut

Comment: what do you mean ?

Comment: I want to show the Time and Time Out fields of the employee as well.

Comment: change the last section of the query to `select * from TM2`

Answer (score 1):

Just Add a Variable to Specify the Date

```
DECLARE @MyDate DATE
```

Assign the date to the Variable if you want to get the records for a specific date else keep it NULL.

Now, Change your Code of the Common Table Expression TM as below -- To Add the Where Condition

```
;WITH TM
AS
(
SELECT
    EmpID, 
    MIN([TimeIn]) as StartTime,
    MAX([TimeOut]) as EndTime
    FROM @T
       WHERE 
          CAST(ISNULL(@MyDate,GETDATE()-1) AS DATE) = CAST(ISNULL([TimeIn],[TimeOut]) AS DATE)
    GROUP BY EmpId
)
SELECT
    *,
    HoursSpent = DATEDIFF(HOUR, StartTime, EndTime)
    FROM TM
```

When @MyDate = '2018-01-10'

[image]

When @MyDate IS NULL

[image]